# Xml response in string, DidStartElement is not calling NSXMLParser

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsxmlparser

Here I am getting xml response in temp string. I need to get one tag value from that xml response.

```
-(void) httpDataDidFinishLoadingWithData:(NSData *)theData
{
    m_activityLoaded=NO;
    temp=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:[dataLoader httpData]  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"TEMP IS TEMP %@", temp);
    parser=[[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:temp]];
    [parser setShouldProcessNamespaces:NO];
    [parser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:NO];
    [parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
    parser.delegate=self;
    [parser parse];
}
```

The problem is DidStartElement is not even calling after the above parser allocation and ready to parse.

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName
attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if(![elementName isEqual:@"Result"])
        return;
    woeid = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"woeid"];
    NSLog(@"woeid   %@", woeid);
}
```

My XML RESPONSE IS

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Body><woied></woied></Body>
```

Please help me out of this guys. Thanks in Advance

Comment: did you add NSXMLparserDelegate to your .h file

Comment: Yes my friend ,, But still not working

Comment: No delegates methods are calling :(

Comment: then check if your xml is valid or not. I think the problem is in xml.

Comment: lemme post the string response...

Comment: can you please post your xml in string format. If you don't want to post xml then check if it is valid or not on some online xml validator.

Comment: are you getting xml response in temp ?

Comment: yes brother, am getting xml response in string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```
-(void) httpDataDidFinishLoadingWithData:(NSData *)theData
{
    m_activityLoaded=NO;
    temp=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:[dataLoader httpData]  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"TEMP IS TEMP %@", temp);
    parser=[[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:[temp dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [parser setShouldProcessNamespaces:NO];
    [parser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:NO];
    [parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
    parser.delegate=self;
    [parser parse];
}
```

I think this may be work.You were passing wrong data to parser.

Answer (score 0):

? [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:temp]]; ?

Maybe you should create parser with [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:theData];